# Is fixing "Apex Code Quality" issues necessary for passing security review?

Tags: security, isv, security-review, checkmarx, security-scanner

I have fixed all the "Apex Critical Security Risk" issues but there are few apex code quality issues remaining. Some of them are false positives and some are correct. But due to time constraints and also I don't want to change what is working, can I skip these changes? Will I be able to pass the security review without fixing these changes? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_document_responses.htm), you must fix:

> All issues regardless of severity level that aren’t labeled “Code Quality”.

As long as you meet this requirement, you will be fine. Just don't wait too long to fix these issues, as it may affect your ability to scale up to larger customers (e.g. an unrestricted query causes your client's UI to crash in some cases).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox most of soql issues are related to custom metadata and also a few for scripts that run just once we update data for some legacy customers.. thanks for the feedback.